# If two matrices have different characteristic polynomials are they not similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, similar-matrices

This question is very basic, but I couldn't find a definitive answer.

I know that if two matrices are similar, they have the same characteristic polynomial. However, if two matrices don't have the same characteristic polynomial, are they guaranteed to be not similar?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The second statement is the [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) of the first.

Comment: Of course. "if P then Q" is the same as "if NOT Q then NOT p". Now, consider P the statement "two amtrices are similar" and Q "two matrices have the same characteristic polyunomial" and you are done.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The contrapositive of this says if two matrices are similar, then they have the same characteristic polynomial. Suppose $A$ and $B$ are similar. Then $A=P^{-1}BP$ for some invertible matrix $P$. Then

$$\chi_A(t)=\det(tI-A)=\det(tI-P^{-1}BP)=\det(P^{-1}(tI-B)P)=\det(tI-B)=\chi_B(t)$$

because the determinant is multiplicative.

Comment: Thanks! I understand it now :)